# applescript get recipient of current mail

Tags: applescript

I´m in the need to export a huge conversation from osx mail to a csv file. My applescript should work on selected mails. This is what I have:

```
tell application "Mail"
    set selectedMessages to selection
    if (count of selectedMessages) is equal to 0 then
        display alert "Please select some message first"
    end if
    set mailInformation to ""
    repeat with tMsg in selectedMessages
        set mailInformation to mailInformation & "'" & {date received of tMsg} & "';'" & {sender of tMsg} & "';'" & {address of first recipient of tMsg} & "';'" & {subject of tMsg} & "'" & (ASCII character 10) as string
    end repeat
end tell

tell application "TextEdit"
    set theDocument to make new document
    set text of theDocument to mailInformation
end tell
```

**Question: how can I get the recipient of the current mail? It seemas to be a list.**

This is not working:

```
{address of first recipient of tMsg}
```

Thanks!

Comment: thanks! If you post as answer, I can accept it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`address of first recipient of tMsg` is supposed to work.

But why do you first create a list and then flatten it again? This does the same:

`set mailInformation to mailInformation & "'" & date received of tMsg & "';'" & sender of tMsg & "';'" & address of first recipient of tMsg & "';'" & subject of tMsg & "'" & linefeed`